# Is there a website that returns 500 (and other) HTTP response codes for testing?

Tags: testing, httpresponse, http-response-codes

It's occurred to me that it would be useful to have a URL that would always return a 500, for the sake of testing client code that handles getting bad responses. And I can think of other projects that would benefit from URLs that would always return 404s, redirects, etc. Does anyone know of a free website that offers this?

Comment: I don't know of any off hand, but that's a really great idea. Now you'll probably see a few hundred of them pop up :)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I believe http://httpstat.us/ can do that as well.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a site that can return any status code:

http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/status_codes

Comment: Nice site. The only drawback is that it only accepts GET requests. Would be nice if it accepted POST for instance.

Answer (score 11):

In case you can't easily change the *path*, but can configure the *host* easily: http://218.returnco.de/whatever and http://returnco.de:218/whatever

(Disclosure: I run this small service)

Comment: That's a great service, but the ssl certificate seems to be expired

Comment: Well, it's not exactly expired, but issued to some other DNS name of that virtual machine. As the page says: "Don't look too closely at the certificate." It's kind of hard to make a business model out of error codes ...

Comment: Moved the cert to "Let's Encrypt" a while ago, shows up green now, unless I botched the renewal automation.

Answer (score 6):

There's also https://httpbin.org/. You can run this locally:

```
docker pull kennethreitz/httpbin
docker run -p 80:80 kennethreitz/httpbin
```

See https://github.com/postmanlabs/httpbin for more details.